# Using the same database on different versions of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

We have several SQL Server databases at work and we plan to keep all of them in a Database Server. However, while we use SQL Server 2014 in some of the databases, there is also a database (let's say ABC) with the version of SQL Server 2008 R2.

The problem is that; ABC is a database originated from another company and sometimes it is updated by them using scripts, etc. So, this means that we have to go together with the version they use. As far as I know, it is possible to restore a database of version 2008 R2 in the version of 2014 but the reverse operation is not possible (to restore a database of version 2014 in the version of 2008 R2).

So, in that case what is the best way to solve this problem by using the single database (SQL Server 2014) on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate database from the 2014, 2008 compatible. You can dig into the advanced option and you will find creating scripts for triggers, indexes and all dependent objects.

[Generate Scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPoMf.jpg)

[Choose Compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkvuN.jpg)

[Specify Data generating scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V7YQ.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, but generating database does not contain the data and some of the other sql elements. I think it does not seem to be so safe as backup / restore task. With script method, how to transfer data and the other elements? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The server could be 2014.
You just need get SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) version 2008 and generate backup using it.
You could have lots of SSMS versions.